# How to create two (or more), columns in Ionic and make them scroll separately?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app, I would like to create 2 or 3 column layout where the left most column would be list of some sort of parent objects, middle one would list children and third would be used for details.

Starting out with the sample "tabs" project, I decided to see how that would work while using the built in grid system:

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
          <ion-list>
           <ion-item  ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
              <!-- stuff -->
           </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ion-list>
           <ion-item  ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
             <!-- stuff2 -->
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </div>
     </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And the columns are indeed displaying, however, lists cannot be scrolled individually which is what I would like to be able to do. I tried different things, such as making columns consisting of "ion-content" but then only one of them would be showing, or they would be placed on top of each other. My google foo yields no results either, so I would appreciate any help.

#### UPDATE:

Wrapping both lists into "ion-scroll" creates two lists side by side, and allows them to be scrolled separately, but now the lists only take up 50% of the width, while the rest of the screen is just empty. No css adjustments seem to help so far.

#### UPDATE 2:

When using:

The columns will take 100% of screen height.
However, the "feel" is not quite right which makes me think that this may not be the optimal solutions. At times (when near top and bottom of the list) one list can also scroll the others which is quite annoying, so my request for help is still standing.

Comment: have you solved this issue ?